# Inheritance with CppUnitTestFramework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I want to make global classes because I want to do the same initialize across my tests. I tried like that, I've mutiples errors like ambiguous access. Someone have an idea ?

`#include <CppUnitTest.h>`

`using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;`

```
TEST_CLASS(GLOBAL_TEST)
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE(initialize)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage("INITIALIZE");
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(ClassA), public GLOBAL_TEST
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD(ClassA_Test1)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage("ClassA_Test1");
    }
};
```

My errors :

```
Code    Description
C2385   ambiguous access of '__GetTestClassInfo'
C2385   ambiguous access of '__GetTestVersion'  
C2594   'static_cast': ambiguous conversions from 'void (__cdecl     ClassA::ClassA::* )(void)' to 'Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::TestClassImpl::__voidFunc'
```

Comment: errors can be intimidating, nevertheless you should read them and post them here as part of the question

Comment: I added my compiler's errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `TEST_` macros don't support inheritance, but your base class could just be defined as a normal class containing an `Initialize()` method. You'd still have to define a `TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE` function in every derived class though.

```
#include <CppUnitTest.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

class GLOBAL_TEST
{
public:
    void Initialize()
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage("INITIALIZE");
    }
};

TEST_CLASS(ClassA), public GLOBAL_TEST
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE(MethodInitialize)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    TEST_METHOD(ClassA_Test1)
    {
        Logger::WriteMessage("ClassA_Test1");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this kind of code is already used but I wanted to "hide" this part because it's often omited (and i've to review all unit tests).